# Partially mirroring a repository to another repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

Suppose I have two repositories called `repo a` and `repo b` each with a main branch. In each repo I have some similar files that are common between the two main branches and some that are unique to each branch, for instance:

```
└── repo a 
    └── main
        ├── a.py
        ├── b.py
        ├── c.py
        └── x.py
   
└── repo b 
    └── main
        ├── a.py
        ├── b.py
        ├── c.py
        └── y.py
```

I wonder if it is possible to mirror part of a `branch` from one repo to another? So when I commit changes to file `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py` the other repo would be updated without causing conflicts due to having `x.py` or `y.py`. I can see that Gitlab has a [mirroring function](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) but this makes a duplicate repo. In my case the two repos are not exactly the same, I wonder if there is any solution for this?

Comment: I think the question is not _correctly_ setup. A repo does not hold files. A repo holds branches/tags (and other stuff), then the tags/branches point to commits that hold files and history so not sure if you are talking about 2 repos or 2 branches.... or 2 repos with 2 different branches.

Comment: There is no need to any tricks to go on there. You can have a _common_ main branch on one repo, and have a separate main branch on the other repo (same name, no problem) that is a fork of the first main branch. Then, you can pull changes from the _common_ main branch into the _other_ main branch.

Comment: You could keep both branches (with a different name) in a single repo but....

Comment: @eftshift0 if you see the question the two main branch are now exact (also as explained). So fetch / pull may cause conflict. `x` and `y` are the different files in the two mains. `a` to `c` are common between the two branches.

Comment: Did you consider using git submodules?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, you can't do that.

A Git repository is, at its heart, two databases.  One database holds *commits* and other objects, and these objects each have a *unique* number.  The unique number for a commit object is determined by the full content of that object: its metadata plus the saved tree.  Git calls this number a *hash ID* and currently generates such hash IDs using either SHA-1 or SHA-256.<sup>1</sup>  Once the commit is made, no part of it can ever be changed: instead, you make a *new* commit, that gets a new, never-before-used, never-to-be-used again hash ID.  So you only ever *add* commits to a repository: the old ones, once made, are frozen for all time.

(The other database holds names, which humans use to help them out, and Git uses to help humans out, because the raw hash IDs used in the *first* database are distinctly unfriendly to humans.)

This means that the commits in repo **a** are entirely different from the commits in repo **b**.  Any two commits that are different in any way—made by a different person, made at a different time, using a different history, and/or containing different files—are different.

Since each commit in any repository represents the full set of files that will be extracted when that commit is checked out, you can't have files `a.py` through `c.py` shared but file `x.py` unique: the copy of `a.py`, `b.py`, and `c.py` that's in the commit that has `x.py` are frozen that way for all time.

*Composing* multiple separate repositories—where one repository holds, e.g., a *library* (such as the Python Requests library, or the PyYaml library, or whatever), and another repository holds your business logic or whatever—is the usual approach here.  You can compose separate repositories in many different ways, using packaging systems, submodules, or whatever you like: which to use is a matter of opinion.

---

<sup>1</sup>The SHA-256 hashes are not in general use yet, but some preliminary support exists for them now, in 2022.  At some point, some kind of migration path must be provided to convert old SHA-1 repositories to new SHA-256 repositories, presumably with some kind of backwards compatibility features, and the backwards-compatibility stuff does not exist yet.